# Como posso verificar se todas as textbox estão vazias?

Tags: c#, winforms

Código:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNumero.Text) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtTitle.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Preencha todas as informações");
}
```

Tentei fazer com && e não funciona, como posso fazer? Quero verificar duas ou mais textboxs

Comment: `&&` quer dizer que as duas tem que estar vazias, se uma só estiver, não entra no seu `if`, troque para `||`

Comment: Ah era coisa boba haha, obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se deseja verificar todos os *textBoxes* a melhor forma e criar um método dinâmico(imagine uma tela de cadastro onde tiver uma grande quantidade de *textBoxes*)

```
private bool textBoxVazias()
{
   foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
      if (c is TextBox)
      {
         TextBox textBox = c as TextBox;
         if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox.Text))
            return true;
      }
    return false;
}
```

Apos criar o método, basta chama-lo e caso o retorno for positivo, algum textBox esta vazio.

```
if(textBoxVazias()) MessageBox.Show("Preencha todas as informações");
```

Caso ainda prefira especificar os campos, ou se eles forem poucos como em seu exemplo, basta utilizar || (ou) ao invés de && (e)

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNumero.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtTitle.Text))
    MessageBox.Show("Preencha todas as informações");
```